# Sql Server wierd query optimization

Tags: sql-server

So I had this query I was going to optimize but nothing seemed to improve the speed, and any indexes I added only worsened the query speed. Except my final solution where the running time dropped from 12 to ca 2-3s.

I also did a few other tries but they where slower and any indexes I added only worsened the query speed.

So the question Is if anyone would like to elaborate on how and why the final query can be faster than the other solutions. Table is about 2m records.

```
--Original
select count(*)
from d d0
left join d d1 on d1.key_v=d0.key_v and d1.key_t=d0.key_t and d1.n_value=1
left join d d2 on d2.key_v=d0.key_v and d2.key_t=d0.key_t and d2.n_value=2
left join d d3 on d3.key_v=d0.key_v and d3.key_t=d0.key_t and d3.n_value=3
where d0.n_value=0
and (d0.value=100) 
and (d1.value=11) 
and (d2.value=22) 
and (d3.value=33 or d3.value=333)

--Final query 
select sum( case when d0.value=100 
                and d1.value=11
                and d2.value=22
                and (d3.value=33 or d3.value=333) 
            then 1 else 0 end)
from d d0
left join d d1 on d1.key_v=d0.key_v and d1.key_t=d0.key_t and d1.n_value=1
left join d d2 on d2.key_v=d0.key_v and d2.key_t=d0.key_t and d2.n_value=2
left join d d3 on d3.key_v=d0.key_v and d3.key_t=d0.key_t and d3.n_value=3
where d0.n_value=0 and (d0.value=100)
```

Is the conclusion that "sum case when" is faster than "count & where"

**UPDATE**
As you all assumed there is a difference in estimated execution plan. But how can I hint the query optimizer to go for the larger one which is faster.

table structure is:

```
key_v(PK, int, not null)
key_t(PK, int, not null)
n_value(PK, int, not null)
value(PK, int, not null)
```

and only 1 index is present:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[d] ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_d] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [key_v] ASC,
    [key_t] ASC,
    [n_value] ASC,
    [value] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Does the order of columns in index matter?

[image]

[image]

So the second is the faster one. the 1st query seems like the way you should wriet a query. And I'm thinking I should add indexes so that it works according to the second query plan. But perhaps that wont work and I should just leave it as query2?

Comment: For any advice on tuning/performance please add details of the table schemas/data types/indexes and add the original actual execution plan and final excution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: Why are you `LEFT JOIN`ing to `d1`, `d2`,  and `d3` in the original query when all 3 must have a non-`NULL` value on the column `value`? It's *impossible* for the column to have a non-`NULL` value if no row was found.

Comment: Looking at your query I suspect there's room for improvement, I can't see and reason to join 3x to `d` when you can join once and include `n_value` in the `case` expression.

Comment: Re "Is the conclusion that "sum case when" is faster than "count & where" - my conclusion would be "left join is often more optimizable than inner join" :)

Comment: You might consider experimenting with OPTION (RECOMPILE) on those statements or DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('SQL Plans'), if it is a dev/test environment. Those are two ways of clearing the query plan cache or clear all adhoc query plan cache for the instance. This just ensures a bad plan has not been cached. However, since you are not parameterizing the  query and all values are static, I doubt that to be an issue but it would not hurt to rule it out. You may also consider updating statistics on those tables if they are not auto updated. Finally, you should examining the actual query plans.

Comment: We could definitely complain about the query and why it needs to join on itself. I don't know why or if it needs to look this way but. I've Been experimenting with option(recompile) and switching to inner joins but nothing improved the query.

Comment: Do you have this index : CREATE INDEX X ON d (value, n_value, key_v, key_t) ?

Comment: You might want to try a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you say the indexes are making the situation worse, it would mean that the query optimizer is following wrong hints, most likely the indexes you defined are not adequate for your situation. Basically you will focus on the fields being joined or searched. Need to see table structure and index definition for more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I ad a columnstore index on the columns in the where clause the performance increased drastically

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX [count_index] ON [dbo].[d]
(
    [name_v],
    [value]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That's somewhat to be expected - I would however be mindful if your table is frequently updated and monitor performance over time if so as columstore indexes in this scenario yield dimishing returns

Answer (score 0):

Without the execution plan or source tables/indexes, it's hard to validate the reason for the performance difference but I'd suggest taking a look at [SQL Server order of operations](https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/). Of note is that FROM (with joins) happens first with WHERE happening second.

1. Your FROMs are identical suggesting the improvement is in the WHERE clause.
2. Your new WHERE clause only looks at 2 fields. This can improve performance if those 2 fields are more effectively indexed for this execution plan and based on their data type (among other possibilities). This could result in an index seek vs a table scan improving performance.

Please note, this is a cursory review. As mentioned in the comments, a more in depth review would require the execution plan and source tables/indexes.